# swagger 2 spring boot - having 2 APIs of the same name but only display one of it

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger-2.0

I have 2 APIs with the same name for a reason.

First one

```java
@ApiOperation(value="")
@RequestMapping(value="/predict", method= RequestMethod.POST, produces="application/json", headers="content-encoding=gzip")
public ResponseEntity<?> predictBinary(HttpServletRequest requestEntity,  @RequestHeader Map<String, Object> header) {
```

Second one

```java
@ApiOperation(value="")
@RequestMapping(value="/predict", method= RequestMethod.POST, produces="application/json", consumes="application/json")
public ResponseEntity predict(@RequestBody RequestInput inputs, @RequestHeader Map<String, Object> header) {
```

Is there a way to only display the second one? Right now swagger randomly chooses one to display, sometimes I see the `First one` sometimes I see the `Second one` I tried removing the @ApiOperation for the `First one` it doesn't help.

Comment: @HIDDEN annotation: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-2.X---Annotations#hidden

Answer (score 0):

You might try to change one's path like now both using /predict its possible that spring controller might have an issue of ambiguous so it's better to use the different route for each and maybe same happen with swagger as well so its fetches those API details randomly